# Dolbeault cohomology of $S^{2n-1} \times S^1$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $X=S^{2n-1} \times S^1$. I have to compute $H^{(1,0)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$ and $H^{(0,1)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$. I don't know how to do this but if we use Kunnet formula we have that $dim(H^{(0,1)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X))+dim(H^{(1,0)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X))=1$, so we have that $H^{(1,0)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)\simeq \mathbb{C}$ and $H^{(0,1)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)\simeq 0$ or vice versa. I find that $X \simeq (\mathbb{C}^{n}-\{0\})/\mathbb{Z} $ via the action $d:(z_1, \cdots, z_n) \mapsto(\lambda^dz_1, \cdots, \lambda^dz_n)$ with $n>1$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|\lambda|>1$. Futhermore I read that $H=\bar{\partial}log(|z_1|^2+ \cdots +|z_n|^2)$ represents a non trivial class. But how can I prove that $H$ is a closed but non exact form?

Comment: Should we assume $n>1$?

Comment: @Matt Yes... I wrote it.

Comment: Cross posted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130765/dolbeault-cohomology

Comment: @Matt Yes, I posted also on MO but I don't understand why this form is closed but non exact...